# Windows 11 keeps starting Photos after sleep

Tags: windows-11, windows-task-scheduler, photos

After update to 11th version, every time after the PC wakes from sleep, Windows opens the Photos app. I can't find any setting for turning this off. Suspect it's some kind of event triggering it in the Task Scheduler, but can't trace it down to disable.

Comment: Get SysInternals Autoruns and install / run it. Look for Photos autostart.

Comment: @john Autoruns is good, but Task Manager has a Startup tab now too, and it's a lot simpler.

Comment: Yes. Try both things to find how Photos starts.

Comment: Tried, although no such entry that has Photos at all... I'm wondering whether that's some MS application that decides to start Photos for some reason.